# deleteMany with Mongoose using array

Tags: node.js, post, mongoose

I am trying to batch delete using deleteMany via Mongoose. Currently I have a few rows with check-boxes and a submit button which POSTs an array of IDs to my deleteMany endpoint like this,

```
router.get('/list/batchDelete', secured()).delete(function(req, res) {
  Booking.deleteMany(
      {
        _id: {$in: [req.params.ids]},
      },
      function(err, rowsToDelete) {
        if (!err) {
          res.send(rowsToDelete);
          res.redirect('/list');
        } else {
          res.send(err);
          console.log('Error in batch delete :' + err);
        }
      },
  );
});
```

I can see the `req.params.ids` payload.

```
POSThttp://localhost:8000/list/batchDelete
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 34ms]
Request payload 
ids%5B%5D=5e1da4db2f11682b506fc6c8&ids%5B%5D=5e1da522becbb13f24748012&ids%5B%5D=5e1da57a5c7f911db82e5731
```

But I keep getting `Cannot POST /list/batchDelete`

Please, what am I missing?

I referred to:

[Mongoose Delete Many by Id](https://kb.objectrocket.com/mongo-db/mongoose-delete-many-by-id-932)

[Mongoose Docs: Query.prototype.deleteMany()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-deleteMany)

UPDATE:
I added a post route like this, which now produces 200OK but in the browser JSON view and still no change to the dataset.

```
router.post('/list/batchDelete', function(req, res) {
  const ids = req.body.ids;
  res.send(ids);
  res.redirect('/list');
});
```

Comment: wouldn't `router.get(` mean that it is a get endpoint? I guess you are trying to post.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Well, I thought maybe that was the case so I tried a post too but still got the same error.

Comment: What is the new error when you changed router.get with router.post?

Comment: Hi @SuleymanSah, thank you, the error was exactly the same however, I have also now added a post route like this `router.post('/list/batchDelete', function(req, res) {
  const ids = req.body.ids;  res.send(ids);   res.redirect('/list'); });` then the browser gets 200Ok but with the JSON view in browser and no change to the dataset, so I assume I must now render or redirect but why doesn't either of my redirects work?

Comment: Please stick with the original problem, what is the problem now? Does the post request hit the api? If it hits, does the deleteMany work?

Comment: Thank you, the post request doesn't seem to reach the API as there is no change to the DB. I just added the above code as a post endpoint to try get some more details, I seem to be receiving the correct array data but Mongoose doesn't seem to run `deleteMany`.

Comment: Can you add console.log("body: ", req.body) at the beginning inside the router.post to check if the request arrives or not?

Comment: Thank you, yes I added it in the post router and the output in the console is `body:  { ids:
   [ '5e1da57a5c7f911db82e5731',
     '5e1da5995bb0a829545c2b6c',
     '5e1da5ad1173c61300b6697c' ] }` Which according to the reference I followed should be accepted by Mongoose deleteMany but nothing happens.

Comment: Change  `_id: {$in: [req.params.ids]}`,  to `_id: {$in: req.body.ids},`

Comment: Thank you, Ok I tried that and get `Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client` in the console but can see the JSON results in the browser

Comment: Delete       res.redirect('/list');, you cannot use res two times,  but I guess delete worked?

Comment: I tried and removed redirect from the get and post routes one at a time to test but still nothing, and unfortunately delete did not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use your route like this

```js
router.post('/list/batchDelete', async (req, res) {
  const {ids} = req.body;
    await Booking.deleteMany(
      {
        _id: {$in: ids},
      })
    return res.send('record deleted');
});
```

Use postman for api call

Call should be POST and on /list/batchDelete route 
Body should contain array of ids 
e.g {"ids":['id1','id2']}

This will solve your problem of deleting records.